# Multiple Google Calendars with one Google Cal ID

Tags: google-calendar

I have a Google Calendar account that has multiple shared calendars and a main calendar. The shared calendars can be edited by other users to put events into each one of those calendars. I would then like to be able to use the main calendar's Google Cal ID to link others to the main calendar and have them see all the events from the other shared calendars overlayed. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Unless the main calendar is shared what you describe is not possible.  Even then what you want to do exactly is not clear.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry I was not clear. I am having a difficult time describing what I would like to do. Basically, I would like to use one Google Cal ID to show the events of multiple shared calendars.

Comment: Are you specifically asking how to do this within Google Calendar?

Comment: @Ramhound Ideally yes, I would like to know how to do this (if possible) within Google Cal. However, any way to have multiple shared calendar's events represented by one Google Cal ID, would be an acceptable answer.